# Laravel json() response returning values twice

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have set up a model `User` and I created a controller to get some values:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Dingo\Api\Routing\Helpers;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

use App\Models\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    use Helpers;

    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();

        return $users;
    }
}
```

But when I run this, the json value is returned twice:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "0": "Firstname Lastname",
      "1": "Accusantium commodi repellat quia eos. Cumque debitis qui deserunt aspernatur harum vitae aut.",
      "2": 1,
      "3": "2016-12-04 21:56:59",
      "4": "2016-12-04 21:56:59",
      "name": "Firstname Lastname",
      "profile": "Accusantium commodi repellat quia eos. Cumque debitis qui deserunt aspernatur harum vitae aut.",
      "house_id": 1,
      "created_at": "2016-12-04 21:56:59",
      "updated_at": "2016-12-04 21:56:59"
    },
}
```

But, a strange thing: the response above is when I have an empty `$visible[]` array in my User model. But when I set the `$visible` to contain, for example, `name` and `profile` both values are only displayed once. What is the problem here? Why is it showing up twice?

Comment: What is your result when you use `return $users->toJson();`?

Comment: No difference, values are returned twice again.

Comment: what is your `Users` model structure?

Comment: Do you have `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` set in your database connection options (look in your `config/database.php` file)?

Comment: No, but setting `'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,` in my database config fixed the problem!

Comment: @Jordy What was it before?

Comment: I didn't set `fetch` at all (Lumen application)

Comment: had an answer to that?

Answer (score 0):

You must convert your result to an array

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::all()->toArray();

    return $users;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return data like this, since you are using dingo api.

```
public function index()
{   
     $users = User::all();

    return $this->response->array($users->toArray());
}
```

You can refer : https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Responses